# add and remove html elements to jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a JS variable like this:

`var elmnts = $('#elm1, elm2, #elm3, #elm4')`

how can i add and remove other html elements?

i try this code but there is no result.

`elmnts.add('#elm5');`

`elmnts.remove('#elm1')`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ? What makes you say `add` wasn't working ?

Comment: how can check values in `elmnts`? how can i do this with forin loop?

Answer (score 1):

[`$.fn.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) returns new collection, it doesn't modify original one. So you should use this syntax.

```
elmnts = elmnts.add('#elm5');
```

To remove element from a collection of jQuery objects you can use [`$.fn.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
elmnts = elmnts.not('#elm1');
```

You should not use `remove` for this, it's used to delete element from DOM tree.

Comment: how can check values in elmnts?

Comment: i try with this code but there is no appropriate result

Comment: `for (var i in elmnts) {
            alert(elmnts[i])
        }`

Comment: What are your elements, inputs, divs?

Comment: my elements are inputs

Comment: then you should use `val()`: `elmnts.each(function() { alert($(this).val()); })`;